# const char * overwritten in next iteration of while loop

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, vector, struct

First of all, everything is happening in an if{} statement in a do{}while loop.  I have a struct that contains some `const char` pointers.  I'm trying to get info into a temp struct with new string values each iteration, then push this struct into a vector of said structs, so that when the function exits, the vector is populated with different struct objects.

```
do{
   if()
   {
     sound_device_t newDevice;  //<--- Why is this the same mem address each iteration?
                                //I thought it would be destroyed when it's scope was (the if block)


     const char * newPath;
     someFunction(&newPath); //puts a string into newPath
     newDevice.firstString = newPath;   //<-- This works.

     QString otherPath(const char *);
     //...some QString manipulation...//
     newDevice.secondString = otherPath.toLocal8Bit().data();  //<--this doesn't

     vector_of_structs -> push_back(newDevice);

   }
}while (...)
```

I was under the impression that push_back copied the argument struct's values into its own version.  Why is the QString giving me problems?  I am using QString because it has some good string manipulation functions (i.e. insert and section), but I'll exchange it if I need to for something that works.

I have also tried putting the QString's data into a char * and then strcpy'ing it into the struct, but that has the same result.  Every iteration rewrites newDevice.secondString.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: any reason for not using append instead of push_back? Also, why not use a QStringList? `QString otherPath(const char *);` is invalid, btw. Also, can you summmarize what "does not work" means? Is newDevice.secondString a char*?

Comment: storing `const char*` for later ... why not using `std::string` or in that case `QString`? does `someFunction(const char**)` allocate on the heap?

Comment: Thanks for replying @LaszloPapp. I don't see append in the std::vector class.  I'm looking at [this page.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)  And I've never heard of a QStringList. :)  Mostly, though, I'm trying to avoid too many Qt libs because I'm trying to make my program as small as possible.

Comment: Hey @Zaiborg. I began using const char * because I'm interacting with DBUS and all the functions take const char *.  I tried using std::string in this case, but it also didn't work.  I have no idea if someFunction() allocates on the heap.  How do I check that?  (It's a DBUS function.)

Comment: Please do not edit the *question* to indicate that it is solved, or that you've added a new answer to it.

Answer (score 2):

[`QByteArray::data()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qbytearray.html#data) is only valid so long as the ByteArray is unchanged. Destroying the temporary is changing.

In other words after the semi colon of the line `newDevice.secondString = otherPath.toLocal8Bit().data();` the QByteArray returned by `toLocal8Bit` is destroyed and the stored array `delete`d.

Comment: Hey @ratchet freak. Ah, OK.  I saw something like that in the QString documentation, but wasn't sure.  Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: @MrUser allocate your own buffer or store the QString in the struct, I'd prefer storing the QString so I don't have to deal with the memory management myself (and do the same for firstString)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

- if statement without condition (!)
- invalid construction: QString otherPath(const char *); You probably want an "otherPath" variable there similarly to "newPath".
- You are mixing qt types with std containers. You should take a loo at QStringList.
- Needless pointer usage: newDevice.secondString = otherPath.toLocal8Bit().data();

The last one is especially critical since you destroy otherPath before the next iteration. The solution is to use a deep copy in there.

I would write something like this:

```
do {
   if(cond) {
     sound_device_t newDevice;    

     const char * newPath;
     someFunction(&newPath);
     newDevice.firstString = newPath;

     // Get other path
     QString otherPath(otherPath);
     //...some QString manipulation...
     newDevice.secondQString = otherPath;
     // or: strcpy( newDevice.secondString, otherPath.toLocal8Bit().data());

     vector_of_structs->push_back(newDevice);

   }
} while (...)
```

That being said, depending on what you are trying to do, QtMultiMedia might be better used overall for your sound device purpose. As long as dbus goes, there is also a QtDBus add-on module.

Comment: Of course my if() has a condition. :)  I just didn't include it because I didn't think it was important for the question.  There is also a const char * allocated in the code that I send to the QString constructor.  I just put `QString otherPath(const char *);` again for simplicity.  Thirdly, I didn't think I could just send a QString object to a const char *.  First it needs to be converted to a const char * (which is what I thought toLatin1().data() did)

Comment: @MrUser: you have not read carefully. newDevice.second*Q*String, but if you really want to avoid that for some reason, strcpy is your friend with manual allocation just as it is already mentioned in the answer... you have not read it carefully, have you ...

Comment: Thank you for all the edits, @Laszlo Papp.  I am reading them as you post them.  I would love to use strcpy, but this is not possible since secondString is a const char * and strcpy only allows to copy to a nonconstant char *.  I will try to make it a nonconstant char * and report back.

Comment: well, you could do this, but it is even uglier: `char *tmp_data = new char[otherPath.toLocal8Bit().size()]; strcpy(tmp_data, otherPath.toLocal8Bit().constData()); newDevice.secondString = const_cast<const char*>(tmp_data);` or `strcpy( const_cast<char*>(newDevice.secondString), otherPath.toLocal8Bit().data());`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help guys.  I got the original code working with just one tweak:

```
newDevice.secondString = otherPath.toLocal8Bit().data();
```

should be changed to

```
newDevice.secondString = strdup(otherPath.toLocal8Bit().data());
```

This does the buffer allocation directly, as @ratchet freak was suggesting.  strcpy() doesn't work because it still connects  newDevice.secondString with the QByteArray, just like toLatin1().data() does.

Comment: Huh? Strcpy works just fine? The whole point of strcpy is to disconnect, but you really should get rid of this bad design in your code, i.e. dealing with low-level strings, IMHO.

Comment: I don't think I see what you mean.  I said strcpy DOES NOT work fine.  I'm using low-level strings because that's the interface provided to me by DBUS, as I already said above.  Thank you for the continued interest, though.  I appreciate the follow-up.

Comment: I do not think you understand what strcpy does; sound_device_t is _not_ provided by dbus.